# A better way to write this TSQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a better way to count values from 2 related tables, right now I join the "root" with 2 "loose related tables"

```
select R.ID 
     , IsNull(I.[count],0) as [IpWithIncidents]
     , IsNull(x.[count],0) as [IpWithOutIncident]
from [dbo].[ISPRange] as r
left outer join (select R.[ID]
                      , count(distinct i.[CIDR]) AS [count] 
                 from [dbo].[Incidents] as i 
                 join [dbo].[ISPRange] as R on i.[CIDR] between R.[CIDR_FROM] and R.[CIDR_TILL] 
                 group by R.[ID]
                 ) as I on i.[ID]=r.[ID]

left outer join (select R.[ID]
                      , count(distinct v.[CIDR]) as [count] 
                      from [dbo].[VisitStats] as v 
                      join [dbo].[ISPRange] as R on v.[CIDR] between R.[CIDR_FROM] and R.[CIDR_TILL] 
                      where v.[Incident] = 0 
                      group by R.[ID]
                ) as x on x.[ID] = R.[ID]

where (R.[ID]= @RangeId or @RangeId is null)
```

Added link to execution plan
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqeBLgyZtSGag_ou1PCoBCS7z1iEJw?e=zdMuQC

Comment: This is a standard approach, and there is nothing wrong with it, per se.

Comment: It seems you could add `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause due to the query being a "catch-all"/"kitchen sink" query.

Comment: @Larnu, please explain

Comment: [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/), [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `apply()` here and will likely see a more efficient plan.

Without a minimal reproducible example I can't test the following but using `outer apply` like this should be equivalent:

```
select r.ID,
    IsNull(i.cnt,0) as IpWithIncidents,
    IsNull(x.cnt,0) as IpWithOutIncident
from dbo.ISPRange r
outer apply(
    select Count(distinct i.cidr) cnt
    from dbo.incidents i
    where i.id = r.id 
        and i.cidr between r.cidr_from and r.cidr_till
)i
outer apply(
    select Count(distinct v.cidr) cnt
    from dbo.VisitStats v
    where v.id = r.id 
        and v.Incidient = 0 
        and v.cidr between r.cidr_from and r.cidr_till
)x
where R.Id = @RangeId or @RangeId is null
```

Comment: You are correct, however, if I execute the 2 the apply query is 88% of the execution time, not sure why that is as it needs to read less data, it is however slower

Comment: @WalterVehoeven It will require suitable indexes for Id and cidr, the execution plan and using `statistics IO` will indicate the differences.

Comment: True,   
Total execution time:  me= 95 You: 125
Client processing time: me=4 You=67, it makes no sense, however that is what it tells me

Comment: @WalterVehoeven I have used the exact same pattern in other situations with good performance; it should be more performant since it's doing fewer joins, however the optimiser clearly is unable to generate the best plan; seeing the tables' schema and indexes in a reproducable example would be the only way to understand further; can you also test without the use of a @variable?

Comment: Grouped apply and grouped join are usually fully interchangable by the optimizer anyway, it rarely makes a difference which way you write it

Comment: Did you add the `RECOMPILE` option as I suggested @WalterVehoeven ? It would be unfair to compare the 2 if one is cached with a plan for `NULL` and the other a non-`NULL` value.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I did, the OPTION(RECOMPILE) was 1 % slower on my tests, translated to Total execution time: YOU= 76, ME= 13. However I feel that fully parameterised call if the SP may show a difference over time

Comment: It would be good to include the execution plans, using paste the plan then @WalterVehoeven . I agree with Stu, this *should* be faster, which suggests there's an unknown quantity being added here we don't know about.

Comment: @Larnu, updated the question, added the plan

Comment: That looks like a link to OneDrive, @WalterVehoeven , not an execution plan. You'll find many users, including myself, won't download files from a file sharing site from strangers.

Comment: @WalterVehoeven please use [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) to share the actual execution plan for each query.

Comment: @Stu. Cool tool, Here is the original https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1NSTGtWF, there is yours https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1M96fKWF

Comment: @Larnu, you can likely view then in notepad, all but the image that is...

Comment: I note the lack of `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` there @WalterVehoeven . Looking at the plan it *looks* like the RDBMS was running a query where the parameter had the value `NULL` but the cached plan a non-`NULL`, as the estimated and read rows are greatly different (8,000 and 50,000 respectively). That or your statistics are *very* out of date.

Comment: @Larnu, run an update statistics, looks a lot better now mine= https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r14SU7FWF, Stu's query= https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1Q68mtWK, mine is now 15% of the batch

Comment: I was about to comment on the previous plan (the index scan vs seek & spool was the problem). Now the plans are different with much better statistics being used and both doing an index seek. There's nothing to choose between them now with both having 0.000s for timings. You can *ignore* the 15%/85%, that's *estimated*, even in the actual plan and means nothing. I'd still wager the apply() was the better query - can you run both with `set statistics io on` and compare *logical reads*. Use [this tool](http://statisticsparser.com/) to quickly analyse the output.